# Xamarin Forms Authenticate with Azure AD

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

I am using this code to Auth with Azure AD ,

```
 public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string[] scopes, string clientId, string redirectUri)
  {
      try { 
      var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
          .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
          .WithAuthority(authority)
          .Build();
      var currentActivity = DependencyService.Get<IAndroidMethods>().GetCurrentActivity();
          var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes )
         .WithParentActivityOrWindow(currentActivity)
         .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
         .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

      return authResult;
  } catch (MsalException ex) {
          await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", ex.Message, "OK"); }
      return null;
     
  }
```

but the AcquireTokenInteractive method never returned  ,
even in Debug , its never back with authResult
what could be this issue ?